# Flutter - Get or access to matching map(s) from a List of Maps

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I have a list of maps.

```
[
  {
    'name': 'name1',
    'age': 30,
  },
  {
    'name': 'name2',
    'age': 20,
  },
  {
    'name': 'name1',
    'age': 15,
  },
]
```

I need to access to `'name': 'name1'` map from above list.

-- Access or extract maps --

i. e. `List[0]` and(or) `List[2]`

### How do I do this kind of thing???

Comment: @OMiShah if I don't know the index?

Comment: Actually, your question was not clear to me earlier but now I get what you're looking for, as answered by  @Yeasin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the list and find items, `.where` will return list of found item. `.firstWhere` for single item return.

```dart
 final data = [
      {
        'name': 'name1',
        'age': 30,
      },
      {
        'name': 'name2',
        'age': 20,
      },
      {
        'name': 'name1',
        'age': 15,
      },
    ];

    final findValue = "name1";

    final result = data.where((element) => element["name"] == findValue);
    print(result); //({name: name1, age: 30}, {name: name1, age: 15})

    result.forEach((element) {
      print("${element["name"]} ${element["age"]}");
    });
```

More about [List](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: shouldn't instead of ``==`` equality operator we should use ``compareTo()`` to compare two strings?

Comment: Can be, but `==` seems easier for this & will work fine

Comment: Thanks dude. This is what I've been looking for. :)